# "to be invited" vs "being invited"

Tags: passive-voice, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

I try to say

> It's a great honor ***to be invited***/***being invited*** by you.

Which one is correct? If both are correct, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are both correct.

There is no difference in the meaning.